# IF Statement is FALSE instead if Zero

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, sumifs

Here is some sample data in a Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cIP118xPmNxMVv0vlpxZ7igp5pVr000f0H8RRILCQIw/edit#gid=0

I would like to return the sum of Pick Up if a column contains Pick Up, and the sum of Actuals if it doesn't (in that case all texts in the column would be Actuals).

Here is the formula I have tried: In this case when the ( "Pick up" Sum range is all 0, it returns it as False but I need it to be $0.00)

```
=IF(
  SUMIFS(C1:C5,B1:B5,"Pick Up"),
  SUMIFS(C1:C5,B1:B5,"Pick Up"),
  SUMIFS(C1:C5,B1:B5,"Actuals")
)
```

Comment: Your formula doesn't really make any sense to me *unless* 0 is counted as False. What else is the If supposed to work off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this Google Sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13a4ZcgFu-yRiyZohXmh0aDnW0EheTOGElXvyQ0WHeHI/edit#gid=0

You want to make your condition a COUNTIFS, so that if Pick Up is found in the column it returns the first option and if not the second:

```
=IF(
  COUNTIFS(B1:B5, "Pick Up")>1, 
  SUMIFS(C1:C5, B1:B5, "Pick Up"), 
  SUMIFS(C1:C5, B1:B5, "Actuals")
)
```

Actually, the SUMIFS in the second option for Actuals isn't really necessary.  If the only thing in the column is Actuals, then you can just use SUM:

```
=IF(
  COUNTIFS(B1:B5, "Pick Up")>1, 
  SUMIFS(C1:C5, B1:B5, "Pick Up"), 
  SUM(C1:C5)
)
```

Hope this helps.

---

### The original answers are below.  I edited them after sample data and clarity on the question was provided.  They are left for historical purposes, or if someone looks at the edit history on the question, or if the edit isn't accepted.

EDIT: based on feedback in the comment.  If you want to return the sum of Actuals when there are no Pick Ups, change the sumifs condition to countifs:

```
=IF(
  COUNTIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Pick Up") > 0,
  SUMIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Pick Up"),
  SUMIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Actuals")
)
```

---

Original answer:

It's a little hard without some actual data, but I think your issue is that if your condition (the sumifs using "Pick Up") returns 0 then that's a falsy value, so it goes to the second output.

```
=IF(
  SUMIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Pick Up"),
  SUMIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Pick Up"),
  SUMIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Actuals")
)
```

Try this instead:

```
=IF(
  SUMIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Pick Up") >= 0,
  SUMIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Pick Up"),
  SUMIFS(X97:X126,$D97:$D126,"Actuals")
)
```

That way if the sumifs returns 0 (or greater) then you will get an explicitly TRUE value to use in the first part of the if, instead of a number that Excel is going to try to interpret as boolean.

Comment: Bingo! that works

Comment: Glad to hear it worked.  If that resolves your problem consider accepting the answer.

Comment: So I got it to work with the >=0, statement however when I only have "Actuals" data in returns 0. instead of the sum.

Comment: This is the formula I used =IF(SUMIFS(W97:W126,$D97:$D126,"Pick Up")>=0,SUMIFS(W97:W126,$D97:$D126,"Pick Up"),SUMIFS(W97:W126,$D97:$D126,"Actuals"))

Comment: Do I need to add an IFS instead of IF

Comment: I cant add a screen shot in here not sure if you understand the issue?

Comment: Perhaps you can make a google sheet with some sample data.  I think sumifs is always going to return at least 0, unless there's some error in the sheet.  And I think you have not accounted for all the cases that might apply.  If you want to base the return value on whether or not there are Pick Ups, you might want to use a countifs instead of a sumifs as your condition, but again without data and a full understanding of the problem, it's just guessing.

Comment: check that edit to the answer.  Again, I am guessing as to the structure of your data and the potential cases and expected outputs.

Comment: Here you go. The formula would need to go into 1 cell only to get all the desired results based on if its " Actual " or if its "Pick Up"

Comment: Check this sheet.  If this is right I'll edit my answer. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13a4ZcgFu-yRiyZohXmh0aDnW0EheTOGElXvyQ0WHeHI/edit#gid=0

Comment: changed the share options on the sheet so you can view it

Comment: FANTASTIC!!!! Yes Chris this is what I was looking for and it works perfectly! great work

Comment: I may go back and edit your question, too, so that the information I had is available to anyone who might view in the future.